# Objective C - Annotation title (null) first time you add a pin, then displays annotation correctly second time

Tags: objective-c, location, mkannotation, cgpoint

I have different pins on top of a map. Each one of them has an annotation that displays the address of that location. The first one is the user location, and it shows the address correctly. The second one lets the user search for a location and it adds a pin showing the address as an annotation. The third one lets the user add a pin by tapping on the screen and is supposed to show the address as the annotation, but it only shows it after the second time a user adds a pin, not the first time. The first time the NSLog returns (null) and after the second time it does return the address. Any help is appreciated.

Here's that part of my code:

```
@implementation SearchAddressVC {
NSString *address;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.mapView.delegate = self;
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
if(locationManager == nil){
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    if(NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_8_0){
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
}
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 500;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
////
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addPin:)];
recognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
self.geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init]; 
}
- (void)addPin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

if (recognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    return;
}
CGPoint userTouch = [recognizer locationInView:self.mapView];
[self.mapView removeAnnotations:[self.mapView annotations]];
Location *point = [[Location alloc] init];
point.coordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:userTouch toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
[[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point.coordinate.latitude, point.coordinate.longitude) completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse* response, NSError* error) {

    if (error == nil) {
        GMSReverseGeocodeResult *result = response.firstResult;
        NSString *street = result.lines[0];
        NSString *secAdd = result.lines[1];

       address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",
                          street,
                          secAdd];
    }
}];
point.title = address;
[self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:point animated:YES];
NSLog(@"%@",point.title);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the last 4 lines of code in the completion handler. I'm guessing the first time its not working because the `GMSGeocoder` takes some time to initialize. Which causes the completion block to be called **after** you've added the annotation.

I think your completionHandler code should look something like this:

```
[[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point.coordinate.latitude, point.coordinate.longitude) completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse* response, NSError* error) {

    if (error == nil) {
        GMSReverseGeocodeResult *result = response.firstResult;
        NSString *street = result.lines[0];
        NSString *secAdd = result.lines[1];

        address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",
                          street,
                          secAdd];

       point.title = address;
       [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
       [self.mapView selectAnnotation:point animated:YES];
       NSLog(@"%@",point.title);
    }
}];
```